# what is the difference between Helper and BaseHelper in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, helper

I want to know the difference between Helper and BaseHelper in Yii2.
Why is there another Helper extended from the Basehelper for each Basehelper in Yii2? 
Should we add our modifications in the extended helper?

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar, but the question needs to be improved adding more detail and explaining the research done before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because with this structure you can simply customize helpers by creating a new class that extends the base helper.

> To customize a core helper class (e.g. `yii\helpers\ArrayHelper`), you should create a new class extending from the helpers corresponding base class (e.g. `yii\helpers\BaseArrayHelper`) and name your class the same as the corresponding concrete class (e.g. `yii\helpers\ArrayHelper`), including its namespace. This class will then be set up to replace the original implementation of the framework.

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-overview.html#customizing-helper-classes